# Is T | null | undefined a good Maybe<T> type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working in a codebase that has a `Maybe<T>` defined as such:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined
```

Both `null` and `undefined` seem to indicate that something is absent, and i am expected to do:

```
if(foo==null){}
```

instead of

```
if(!foo){}
```

The biggest offender seems to be that i can't mix this with an optional parameter, somewhere below:

```
type Props<T> = {
  foo: Maybe<T>
  bar?: T // "built in Maybe" in my mind
}

const C = (props: Props<number>) => {
  const { bar, foo } = props

  return (
    <>
      <C foo={foo} bar={bar} />
      <C foo={foo} bar={foo} /> //bar={foo} errors
      <C foo={bar} bar={bar} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Also:

```
//invalid
if(!foo?.bar?.baz)
```

```
//valid
if(foo?.bar?.baz != null)
```

This pattern smells to me, since it feels that `foo?` is not the same as `foo!=null`?

```
//what i feel i should be writing with this enforced == against null
if(foo!=null && foo.bar!=null && foo.bar.baz!=null)
```

```
//what i think ? chain does
if(foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz != null)
```

```
//what i think i can do if i use ?, ie ? already breaks != null
if(foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz)
```

I've come up across an example as such:

```
const toMaybe = (v)=>v??undefined
```

This seems to make more sense as it doesn't inherently conflate `null` and `undefined` - i have to be explicit when doing that. It feels i have to be explicit with `null` anyway - eg. i don't get it by accessing an array out of bounds - i get `undefined`. Missing keys on objects don't return `null` etc. Either i have to assign `null` to something, or it's very well documented that some built in method will return `null`.

So `T|null|undefined` is confusing to me, but other than the optional parameter i cant argue against it. Eslint enforces triple equality across the codebase **unless you check against null**. Given that this exemption can be setup, it tells me that it is a valid pattern.

Are there any downsides to including `null` in "maybeness"? Is `==null` a good solution to check for both `undefined` and `null` and is this good practice?

I wouldn't mind having eslint warn me about `Maybe<number>`  but even then i think i would prefer `=== undefined` vs `== null`, i'm not sure why.

Comment: Note that `if(foo==null){}` is not safe, there is at least a third value loosely equal to null and undefined: document.all. As for the rest, it's a more sensible type in languages that have HKTs and don't have untagged unions. You could make a Maybe type in TS but you'd be cutting against the grain.

Comment: T|undefined actually makes sense as a “maybe” null is really messing with my brain.

Answer (score 3):

I have answered a similar question before, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

With TypeScript, there is a *strong* temptation towards writing code like `T | null | undefined`. Resist it.

`null` and `undefined` have different semantic meanings: the former is "value of nothing" while the latter is "no value at all". Or another way, one is it *explicitly* nothing while the other is *implicitly* nothing. These are not interchangeable.

In my opinion, you shouldn't be accepting both `null` and `undefined` if you're not treating them differently. My rule of thumb is that `T | undefined` governs the optionality of a value, while `null` in `T | null` is simply a possible value.

A different good place to use `null | undefined` would be a component that can reasonably accept both. A crude example:

```
interface ElementProps {
  name: string | null | undefined
}
function Element({ name }) {
  if (name === null) return "Name is not available";
  if (name === undefined) return "Name is not set";
  return name;
}
```

This brings us to *why* the temptation to write `T | null | undefined` is there: Because that's how JS behaves in the real world. There is a lot of inconsistency out there.

For example, getting the value of a non-existing index will be `undefined`, while getting the attribute of a non-existent DOM attribute will be `null`. It's up to you to make this consistent. The `??` operator is very helpful when it comes to it to normalizing it inline:

```
<Element name={myPossiblyUndefinedProperty ?? null} />
```

The narrower your API contract, the better. You don't accept `number | string` for math functions because it's unnecessarily broad (even if it will often behave the same). Same story here.

In conclusion, there is no reason to use a `Maybe<T>` type. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: I don't mind the `Maybe<T>` itself, just that it, in my case, covers `null` as well :( When declaring a variable that i will fill later, `Maybe<T>` feels comfortable, vs `|undefined` or `|null = null`. I agree that null should find itself there as `Maybe<number|null>` with different meanings - "not there", "not valid" "is number". It's just that our type got me questioning the need for such granularity between "isnt there" and "isnt valid" :(

Comment: Did you mean to write the comments the other way around? `undefined` seems more like "we haven't even obtained it" whereas `null` feels like "we havent set it's value, but we have it (it's null)"

Comment: Ah, i think i know now at least where this is coming from: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/

Comment: @pailhead Discussing values that mean "nothing" gets my head. I think I did inverse them. `Maybe<>` might feel comfortable but it is ambiguous between code bases (whether `null` is a maybe) and requires inspecting the generic in order to work with it confidently. I like to reserve generics for substantial transformations such as mappings. Unions can stay unions.